# bcsphere Plugin : scan Bluetooth devices & connect to particular device

Tags: cordova, bluetooth

I am using bcsphere library plugin in my cordova project.
Library :--
https://github.com/bcsphere/bluetooth

But most of the examples given does not scan for available devices.
Bluetooth apps :--
https://github.com/bcsphere/apps

Now how to scan for all bluetooth devices & connect to a particular device, using this plugin ?

I found this function, but not getting how to use it :--
BC.Bluetooth.StartScan